# Evitar Nan en un codigo javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código pero si no ingreso un valor al ejecutar el **script** me aparece `NaN`, quisiera que no apareciera y me mostrara una alerta que el campo esta vacío.

```js
function descuento() { 
  var n1 = parseInt(document.calculator.numero1.value);
  document.calculator.resultado.value="$ "+(n1-n1*.15).toFixed() + " Pesos"; 
}
```

```html
<div class="calculadora">
  <form name="calculator"> 
    <div class="botones"> 
      <input class="boton1" type="button" value="DESCUENTO" onclick = "descuento()">
    </div>
    <div class="parrafo"></div>
    <div class="anuncio">
      <span>15% Descuento, Disponible al 30 de Septiembre</span>
    </div>
    <div class="centrado">
      <div class="caja-calculadora">
        <div class="caja-precio">
          <div class="signo">$</div>
          <input class="precio" id="precio" type="text" name="numero1" value=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="anuncio">Precio de Catalogo</div>  
        <div class="linea">

        <div class="anuncio2">TOTAL A PAGAR</div>

      </div>
      <div class="caja-resultado">
        <div class="signo2"><input class= "resultado" id="resultado"  type="text" name="resultado" disabled></div> 
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Qué lenguaje es ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN) nativo de javascript para chequear si es que no es un número.

Por ejemplo:

```
isNaN(NaN) //devuelve true
isNaN("string") //devuelve true
isNaN("12") //devuelve false
isNaN(12) //devuelve false
```

En tu código podrías utilizarlo de la siguiente manera dentro de la función:

```js
function descuento() { 
  var n1 = parseInt(document.calculator.numero1.value);
  
  // muestro el alerta si no es un número
  if (isNaN(n1)) {
    alert('ingrese un número válido.');
  } else {
    document.calculator.resultado.value="$ "+(n1-n1*.15).toFixed() + " Pesos"; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="calculadora">
  <form name="calculator"> 
    <div class="botones"> 
      <input class="boton1" type="button" value="DESCUENTO" onclick = "descuento()">
    </div>
    <div class="parrafo"></div>
    <div class="anuncio">
      <span>15% Descuento, Disponible al 30 de Septiembre</span>
    </div>
    <div class="centrado">
      <div class="caja-calculadora">
        <div class="caja-precio">
          <div class="signo">$</div>
          <input class="precio" id="precio" type="text" name="numero1" value=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="anuncio">Precio de Catalogo</div>  
        <div class="linea">

        <div class="anuncio2">TOTAL A PAGAR</div>

      </div>
      <div class="caja-resultado">
        <div class="signo2"><input class= "resultado" id="resultado"  type="text" name="resultado" disabled></div> 
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: tambien puede ver si es numerico `console.log(Number.isInteger("r"))`

Comment: @JackNavaRow si pero no lo soporta la versión de IE lamentablemente.

Comment: si haces `isNaN('')` esto te retorna false y al momento de hacer parse te retornará NaN de todas formas aconsejo generar el método que envié para prever errores

Comment: Muchas gracias resolvieron mi problema, son todos unos expertos gracias

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` es el diminutivo de *Not a Number* y se crea cuando intentaste hacer `parse` (parseInt) a algo que no era un número por lo que este te retorna ese valor. Antes de usar un valor como número que es ingresado por un usuario te recomiendo comprobar si este es o no un número con la siguiente funcion:

```
function esNumero(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(+document.calculator.numero1.value || 0)` Con solo insertar `+` ya le decis que tiene que ser un número, osea que `null`, `undefined` y `false` serán 0 con el operador de comparación (algo || otro) le decimos que si no se puede convertir a número que sea 0.

Osea que **si el usuario ingresa cualquier cosa que no sea número, incluso nada, sera como si hubiera ingresado cero.**

```js
function descuento() { 
  var n1 = (+document.calculator.numero1.value || 0);
  document.calculator.resultado.value="$ "+(n1-n1*.15).toFixed() + " Pesos"; 
}
```

```html
<div class="calculadora">
  <form name="calculator"> 
    <div class="botones"> 
      <input class="boton1" type="button" value="DESCUENTO" onclick = "descuento()">
    </div>
    <div class="parrafo"></div>
    <div class="anuncio">
      <span>15% Descuento, Disponible al 30 de Septiembre</span>
    </div>
    <div class="centrado">
      <div class="caja-calculadora">
        <div class="caja-precio">
          <div class="signo">$</div>
          <input class="precio" id="precio" type="text" name="numero1" value=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="anuncio">Precio de Catalogo</div>  
        <div class="linea">

        <div class="anuncio2">TOTAL A PAGAR</div>

      </div>
      <div class="caja-resultado">
        <div class="signo2"><input class= "resultado" id="resultado"  type="text" name="resultado" disabled></div> 
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form> 
</div>
```